# Reference for the benefits of Caching

Tags: caching, reference

I am looking for a good reference (Paper, Blog, Book etc.) on how a good caching strategy could benefit - especially web based - applications. I know it is always application specific but I just want to quote some figures about the performance gains possible (or when it doesn't make sense). Would be great if you had some input for me.

Comment: A good example of the benefits of well-applied caching in a web application is http://stackoverflow.com/. Maybe there's a blog entry about it somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some pointers with data:

- http://www.gear6.com/memcached-resources/papers
- http://www.docstoc.com/docs/412119/Technical-White-Papers---Oracle-Coherence
- http://www.terracotta.org/ehcache/distributed-cache/ehcache-ex-performance-whitepaper

Answer (score 0):

There's a decent paper (published in the ACM) called "[Quick and Easy Cache Performance Analysis](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=88241)". You might find it useful.

If you can't download that paper, let me know and I'll send it to you.